# DataGridView - When any cells in a row are changed, I want to prompt the user and save the changes if leaving that row

Tags: c#, datagridview

If a user leaves a row where they made changes to any cells in the `datagridview control`, I want to ask them to save the changes and then save the changes.

The problem is that I can not find the elusive and magical combination of properties and events to get this to work. When I try to call the save routine from events like `RowValidating`, `RowValidated`, `RowLeave`, or `RowStateChanged`, the value of the changed cells, or at least the value of the last cell in the row, is not the new value.
It comes up as the old value before it was changed. It seems to be canceling the edit.

I did look at similar questions here but they did not address my issue. Can someone please help and advise on the best way, or a good way to accomplish this???

Thank you!

Valhalla

Comment: are you familiar with javascript..? check out things like `OnBlur` I believe that this can be a good place to start..

Comment: Is it Winforms? Also: Is the DGV dataBound?

Comment: Try `DataGirdView_CellEndEdit` and `DataGirdView_CellBeginEdit` events, there you can check if value changed and raise your dialog

Comment: Thanks... No I'm using Visual Studio C# and it's DataGridView control for a desktop type application. Wouldn't CellEndEdit, CellBeginEdit and CellValueChanged all trigger around leaving the cell as opposed to leaving the row? I actually did try it unsuccessfully with CellValueChanged. I'm just starting to get familiar with this grid control so I'm green. Do you have to put it in and out of edit mode???

Comment: Don't annoy the end user that way.

Comment: This problem occurs because the user enters data to an invisible text box placed over the cell. It transfers only after the focus moves. We need someone to show how to address the invisible text box directly.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event handler for RowLeave as such:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.dataGridView1.IsCurrentRowDirty)
  {
    this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    // Your prompt to save code.
  }
}
```